# What's the functional version of a nested test?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I'm converting some C++ code to Clojure, and I want
to return a graph `g` with a bunch of edges added to it.
I pass in the the number of vertices, the graph, and
the test predicate (eg, a function that could depend on i, j, randomness, ...) something like this:

```
(defn addSomeEdges [v g test-p]
  (doseq [i (range v)]
    (doseq [j (range (dec i))] 
      (if test-p 
          (add-edges g [i j] )
          )))
  g)
```

the problem, of course, is that `(add-edges)` returns a new `g`.  How can I capture this updated graph using best practices Clojure, please?  It seems so simple and natural in C++.

Comment: It might be useful to see the C++ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterativly accumulating information looks like a reducing function if you split it into two parts:

- Generate a bunch of edges to consider including.
- Test each edge and if it passes, include it. Otherwise pass the result on unchanged

Which can be written using `reduce`

```
user> (defn add-edge [g i j]
        (assoc g i j))
#'user/add-edge

user> (add-edge {1 2} 2 1)
{1 2, 2 1}

user> (defn addSomeEdges [v g test-p]
        (reduce (fn [graph [i j]]        ;; this takes the current graph, the points,
                  (if (test-p graph i j) ;; decides if the edge should be created.
                    (add-edge graph i j) ;; and returns the next graph
                    graph))              ;; or returns the graph unchanged.
                g  ;; This is the initial graph
                (for [i (range v)    
                      j (range (dec i))]
                  [i j])))  ;; this generates the candidate edges to check.
#'user/addSomeEdges
```

and let's run it!

```
user> (addSomeEdges 4 {1 2} (fn [g i j] (rand-nth [true false])))
{1 2, 2 0}
user> (addSomeEdges 4 {1 2} (fn [g i j] (rand-nth [true false])))
{1 2, 3 0}
user> (addSomeEdges 4 {1 2} (fn [g i j] (rand-nth [true false])))
{1 2, 2 0, 3 1}
```

When you think of other tests you can thread these calls together:

```
user> (as-> {1 2} g
        (addSomeEdges 4 g (fn [g i j] (rand-nth [true false])))
        (addSomeEdges 7 g (fn [g i j] (< i j)))
        (addSomeEdges 9 g (fn [g i j] (contains? (set (keys g)) j))))
{1 2, 3 1, 4 1, 5 3, 6 4, 7 5, 8 6}
```

Comment: You could also use `:when` in the `for` to filter out there and simplify the `reduce`.

Comment: the when in a for loop only works if your edges tester is independent of edges added by previous iterations of the reduceing function. if the first edge affected which edges should late be added. some common cases would be loop eliminations, making spanning trees, and minimum connected graphs. if your test fits that criteria, then you can solve this with Justin three for loop, no reduce required.

Comment: thanks so much @ArthurUlfeldt !  reducing over a generator with a filter is a very useful pattern, with spanning trees etc. being the sort of examples i was thinking, too.  but I don't understand this bit of your comment: "think of other tests you can thread these calls together"?   in your comment: so long as the test is not changed by previous additions, it'd also be ok to use just a :when on the generating for loop?

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one solution to this.  Sometimes, though, when you have a fundamentally mutable/imperative problem, you should just use a mutable/imperative solution:

```
; simplest version using mutation
(defn addSomeEdges [v g test-p]
  (let [g-local (atom g)]
    (doseq [i (range v)]
      (doseq [j (range (dec i))]
        (when (test-p i j ...)  ; what other args does this need?
          (swap! g-local add-edges [i j]))))
    @g-local))
```

I was a little uncertain on the semtantics of `test-p`, so that part may need refinement.

Note the `swap!` will call `add-edges` like so:

```
(add-edges <curr val of g-local> [i j])
```

See [the Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) & [ClojureDocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/swap%21) for more info.

Comment: I have yet to find an instance of someone using an ad hoc atom in this fashion where it was not a code smell.

Comment: thanks for this solution, too Alan.  i agree that sometime just being very mutable/impure is fine, but just now i'm trying to remember how to think functionally.  And real clojuristas do seem to get upset about the 'smell' of the alternative.

Comment: You could implement the same thing without an atom using `loop/recur`, but with the dependent nested loops there is much more manual indexing required and more opportunity to get an off-by-one error or similar. Also note that `reduce` uses mutation internally, at the cost of a more complicated arrangement of the code.